# HTML - change div max-width attribute on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `checkbox` and a `div`. My if the `checkbox` is checked then the `max-width` attribute should reduce(the `div` should shrink in size) and vice versa.

```js
function configureMarksTableWidth(checkbox) {
  var marksTable = document.getElementById("table-mark");
  alert(checkbox.checked);
  if (checkbox.checked === true) marksTable.style.maxWidth = "600px";
}
```

```css
#marks-table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /*max-width: 600px;*/
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="configureMarksTableWidth(this)">
<div id="marks-table" style="max-width: 900px">
```

The scenario is this:
If the `checkbox` is checked then the div should be of width `600px` and when unchecked then it should be of width `900px`

I am getting the result of the alert called inside my JS function but nothing changes in the div

Comment: Give that condition in else part?

Comment: Can you use input:checked on css directly and remove the need for js?

Comment: You have `id="marks-table"` and you are using `var marksTable = document.getElementById("table-mark");` this will return `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` change your id in js to match div id.

Comment: If only Atom was as good an editor as IntelliJ........

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal for every unexpected behavior or error just debug your code with debugger or console.log. and you can use `if` to check if element is available then do operation on it

Comment: Can you add breakpoints and step through and evaluate in debugger? That would be really cool @Shahram

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal yes you can add breakpoint in chrome devtools.also in your javascript code by adding `debugger;` for example `function configureMarksTableWidth(checkbox) {
   debugger;
    var marksTable = document.getElementById("marks-table");
    if (checkbox.checked === true)  {
        marksTable.style.maxWidth = "600px"
    } else {
    //if unchecked
        marksTable.style.maxWidth = "900px"
    }
  
}` 
if you run this when u click check box then script will stop and you can use step with devtools and watch variables and call stacks....etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `id="marks-table"` and you are getting `table-mark` this will return `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style'` of null change your id in js to match div id.

**Solution:**

```js
function configureMarksTableWidth(checkbox) {

    var marksTable = document.getElementById("marks-table");
    if (checkbox.checked === true)  {
        marksTable.style.maxWidth = "600px"
    } else {
    //if unchecked
        marksTable.style.maxWidth = "900px"
    }
  
}
```

```css
#marks-table {
      overflow-x: scroll;
      /*max-width: 600px;*/
      border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="configureMarksTableWidth(this)">
<div id="marks-table" style="max-width: 900px">
```

Answer (score 3):

We dont need javascript for doing this we can use

`#check:checked~#marks-table{
     max-width:600px;
}`

```css
#marks-table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-width: 900px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#check:checked~#marks-table {
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<div id="marks-table">
```

but if you still was to do this in javascript then your javascript is correct you just putted the wrong id in the getElementById you have to put marks-table not the table-mark like

```
var marksTable = document.getElementById("marks-table");
```

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal thats because you have inline style `style="max-width: 900px"`. It has top priority and overwrite everything. Place it in your css where you comment out 600px) and all will work with no js.

Answer (score 1):

You used `table-mark` in `getElementById`, not `marks-table`.
It was wrong.
So please change ID like this

```js
function configureMarksTableWidth(checkbox) {
    var marksTable = document.getElementById("marks-table");
    alert(checkbox.checked);
    if (checkbox.checked === true) marksTable.style.maxWidth = "600px";
}
```

```css
 #marks-table {
      overflow-x: scroll;
      /*max-width: 600px;*/
      border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="configureMarksTableWidth(this)">
    <div id="marks-table" style="max-width: 900px">
```

Comment: The div should shrink in size when checkbox is checked **and vice versa**.